# What is the pun in Fowles' The Magus?

Tags: meaning, wordplay, john-fowles, the-magus

Google has not helped me figure this out. This is from the first or second page of the book (I'm not sure exactly since my electronic copy of the book doesn't seem to have page numbers):

> I saw very little of my father during the war, and in his long absences I used to build up a more or less immaculate conception of him, which he generally – a bad but appropriate pun – shattered within the first forty-eight hours of his leave.

I'm guessing there is some kind of informal meaning to "shattered" here? Maybe it has something to do with "immaculate conception"?

Answer (score 8):

It's a double pun on *immaculate conception* and *general*. The Roman Catholic dogma of [immaculate conception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immaculate_Conception) says that Mary is free from original sin right from the moment of her conception.

The narrator is saying that during his father's wartime absences, he would come up with an idealized image of him. This is a *conception* in the sense of "a complex product of abstract or reflective thinking" (sense 2c on the [Merriam-Webster page](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conception)). It was *immaculate*, i.e., spotless, because the narrator would attribute all good qualities to the picture he built up of his father in his mind.

This idealized picture would be shattered by his father's actual behavior upon his returning home for leave. His father is a [brigadier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigadier_(United_Kingdom)), which in the British army is the lowest-ranking of the generals. Directly after the passage you quote, the narrator goes on to say:

> Like all men not really up to their job, he was a stickler for externals and petty quotidian things; and in lieu of an intellect he had accumulated an armoury of capitalized key-words like Discipline and Tradition and Responsibility. If I ever dared—I seldom did—to argue with him, he would produce one of those totem words and cosh me with it, as no doubt in similar circumstances he quelled his subalterns. If one still refused to lie down and die, he lost, or loosed, his temper. His temper was like a red dog, and he always had it close to hand.

So within a couple of days after his father's return, the narrator would see him as he really was: an incompetent, unintelligent, bad-tempered man. His father would behave toward him in the same way that he, in his capacity as general, would behave toward his subordinates in the army. So he would *generally* shatter the *immaculate conception* that the narrator has built up. In this context, "generally" means "wholly" or "entirely" (from definition 1 of entry 1 on the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/general) page), but it also means *in the manner of a general*, referring to his father's rank.

As Tsundoku mentions in the comments, the immaculate conception is not the same as the [virgin birth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_birth_of_Jesus). Jesus's being born of a virgin (because Mary bore the child of God without sexual intercourse) is a different Catholic doctrine from the immaculate conception.

**Edit 20230202**. WS2's comment caused me to revisit this answer and I realized that I had missed what is in hindsight blindingly obvious. [Etymologically](https://www.etymonline.com/word/general), *generally* comes from *genus/genera*, and is thereby related to procreation and conception:

> general (adj.) c. 1200, "of wide application, generic, affecting or involving all" (as opposed to *special* or *specific*), from Old French *general* (12c.) and directly from Latin *generalis* "relating to all, of a whole class, generic" (contrasted with *specialis*), from *genus* (genitive *generis*) "stock, kind" (from PIE root ***gene-** "give birth, beget," with derivatives referring to procreation and familial and tribal groups).

The father's being a brigadier-general ties into this rather elaborate pun. And of course he has begotten the narrator, who is of a different generation ... but perhaps seeing that as part of the pun is stretching things a bit.

Comment: It may be worth adding that the doctrine of [immaculate conception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immaculate_Conception) should not be confused with that of the [virgin birth of Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_birth_of_Jesus). Some people mistakenly think that "immaculate conception" refers to the latter ...

Comment: The strange thing is that, from its placement in the sentence (*"he generally – a bad but appropriate pun – shattered"*), it seems that the "pun" is something about "shattered" rather than "immaculate conception". Am I missing something, or did the author just put the parenthetical in an odd place?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually the *answer* was missing something. I took a look at *The Magus* and realized that the father's being a brigadier, something not evident from the quote in the question, yielded a pun on *generally*. Fixed.

Comment: @Tsundoku as a veteran of Catholic schooling, I take that distinction for granted, but you're right, it's a potential source of confusion. I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Case in point: I learned just now from @Tsundoku's comment that "immaculate conception" doesn't refer to the virgin birth of Jesus :-)

Comment: @verbose I'm about half-way through reading the novel at the moment, but did wonder, when I recently read that passage, early in the book, about what the pun was.  I'm not convinced "immaculate conception" is part of it. (Nor am I even sure that the theological concept enters into it - the term is just a convenient description for how he views his father - I suspect.)  It seems to me that the pun is simply on "generally" on the one hand and the father's rank on the other. Interesting author though he is, Fowles does to my mind tend to be superfluous with his text.

Comment: 'tis groundhog day and I'm back. Missed y'all. (Feel free to delete this comment, mods.)

Comment: @verbose a very small fly which really just adds interest to the ointment of this great answer: Fowles is British, and in the British army a Brigadier is *not* a general rank. It's essentially a senior colonel. That's why other nations use the rank Brigader-General while Britain (and some other commonwealth nations) use Brigadier. So that aspect of the pun really -is- a stretch.

Comment: @MattThrower Thanks for the correction. Is it possible that given the time frame of the novel, the narrator's father was in fact a brigadier-general back when that rank existed in the British army—up to the 1920s, I believe?

Comment: @verbose I haven't read the novel but checking a quick summary that's entirely plausible given the time frames. Which makes the lengths he's gone to to land this pun even more extraordinary :)